# Android: Alarm Manager

Tags: android

This is the code:

```
public void startAlarm(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SyncService.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                10 min, 20 min, sender);

}
```

This is my method where I start my alarm... I use it in my main activity in onCreate method... What if I change something in settings, and I want to change a time of Repeating? How to do that? I should kill that one and start new one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you [read the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) you will notice the following:

> If there is already an alarm scheduled
>   for the same IntentSender, it will
>   first be cancelled.